# Exponential integral representation

Tags: special-functions, exponential-function

According to  [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) eqn. (8)
$\; E_{1}(x) \;$ can be represented by:

$$ E_1(x)= - \gamma  - \ln(x) - \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n n!}  $$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

I observed that this representation is valid or give accurate results for lower values of $x$ only, i.e. $x=0.001, ...,20$. However, for large values of $x$ this representation gives wrong result.

For example, for $x=0.1$, the result is $1.82292$, which is correct. 
For $x=25$, this representation gives $-0.00002210807401$, which is not correct, it should be $5.348899755*10^{-13}$.

Any explanation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, power series representation is not a good choice for larger input, even if the radius of convergence if infinite.

In this case, you need about 90 leading terms just simply to achieve the desired order of magnitude (and more terms for the accurate digits). Indeed, *Mathematica 10.2* confirms that if we let

$$ S_n = -\gamma - \log 25 - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k 25^k}{k!k}, $$

then you can see that we need about 120 leading terms to achieve 20-digit accuracy:

\begin{align*}
S_{10} &\approx -1.8036638952044776218 \times 10^{6} \\
S_{20} &\approx -1.0045038653588617198 \times 10^{8} \\
S_{30} &\approx -4.8147011301872907116 \times 10^{7} \\
S_{40} &\approx -9.5062897788081758876 \times 10^{5} \\
S_{50} &\approx -1.6908961484269455556 \times 10^{3} \\
S_{60} &\approx -4.3435091996295920753 \times 10^{-1} \\
S_{70} &\approx -2.2108074007813609212 \times 10^{-5} \\
S_{80} &\approx -2.7925545196351250856 \times 10^{-10} \\
S_{90} &\approx 5.3384543545972366461 \times 10^{-13} \\
S_{100} &\approx 5.3488997421949443337 \times 10^{-13} \\
S_{110} &\approx 5.3488997553402104337 \times 10^{-13} \\
S_{110} &\approx 5.3488997553402166403 \times 10^{-13}
\end{align*}

This also says that we have horrible cancellations between leading terms, which are much larger compared to the magnitude of $E_1(25)$. So if you use usual floating type variables, then you will certainly lose all the significant digits. For example, [double-precision floating type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) gives 15-17 significant digits, which is clearly inappropriate in our case. I suspect this is the reason why you get different values.

For large $x$, as @gammatester pointed out, other methods are more adequate for numerical purpose.

Comment: first thank you. The last $n$ should be 120 not 110. If I don't know the exact result, how can I find the value of $n$? for example, for the case when $x=100$, how do I estimate the limit of the infinite series?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code it is difficult. But I guess it is catastrophic cancellation. $E_1(25) \approx  5.3488997553\times 10^{-13}$ and the single terms are much larger, e.g. the for $n=10$ the value is $2628070.75729$ and for $n=24$ the term is $238585088.1445781!$ You will get similar problems is you compute $e^{-x}$ or $\sin(x)$ for $x=25$ using the Taylor series.

If you are interesting in actually computing $E_1$ (and not only to get insight in the described problem) you can use the continued fraction http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.9 for say $x>1$.

Comment: there is no code to see. you just plugin the value of x into both formula, and you get the result. so, this representation for the exponential integral function is not correct for all $x$, is that what you mean?

Comment: Where do you plugin the infinite series?

Comment: Once again: **who/what calulates the infinte sum?** If I plugin both sides into Maple, compute with 60 digits and 120 terms I get an error  of $0.120039558\times 10^{-33}$ for $x=25$.

Comment: You are right, for high values of $x$ the continued fraction gives quite accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), there is an interesting expansion for large arguments $$E_1(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {k!}{(-x)^k}$$ For $x=25$, using $n$ terms, we have $$S_1=5.332970444146184 \times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_2=5.350747012293338 \times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_3=5.348613824115680 \times 10^{-13}$$  $$S_4=5.348955134224105 \times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_5=5.348886872202420\times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_6=5.348903255087624\times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_7=5.348898667879767\times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_8=5.348900135786281\times 10^{-13}$$ $$S_9=5.348899607339937\times 10^{-13}$$

**Edit**

As @tired commented, we must take care about the fact that this asymptotic expansion diverges for large values of $k$. In the present case, we start with trouble around $k=50$.

Comment: Maybe you should add that this is an asymptotic expansion, therefore it diverges for every fixed $x$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ but gives very accurate results if one only keeps a finite number of terms. Here things start to get crazy at $n\approx40$